# Append incremental strings to rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, append

| cell | sample |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B1_1_0h |
| 2 | B1_1_0h |
| 3 | B1_1_0h |
| n | B1_1_0h |
| 5140 | B1_1_0h |

I have the above dataframe, where each row corresponds to a cell name and the sample it belongs to in the next column.

I need to alter the text in the first column so that each cell reads "bc000X" where X is the integer and continues until 5140 where it will read "bc5140"

I am having trouble writing a line of code where it will relabel all the rows and incrementally shift the 0's so that is will read bc0010 instead of just adding 10 to the end of bc000.

Any help would be appreciated!

I have been trying to write the code incrementally and manually, but this is very time consuming for all 5140 cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf()` combined with `paste0()` to achieve what you want. In the code below, "%04g" adds 0s without exceeding a maximum integer length of 4:

```r
# Dataframe based on your example data
df <- data.frame(cell = c(1, 2, 3, 100, 5140),
                 sample = "B1_1_0h")

# Update "cell" column in df
df$cell <- paste0("bc", sprintf("%04g", df$cell))
```

Result:

```r
#     cell  sample
# 1 bc0001 B1_1_0h
# 2 bc0002 B1_1_0h
# 3 bc0003 B1_1_0h
# 4 bc0100 B1_1_0h
# 5 bc5140 B1_1_0h
```